# Android : Adding a rectangle shape to a button enlarge him

Tags: android, button, layout

I set a selector to draw rectangle shape to my button like below :

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@android:color/white">
<item>
    <selector>
        <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/disabled_button"/>
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@drawable/classic_radiusbutton_off"/>
    </selector>
</item>
```

and the shape are like this :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/button_radius"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/pink_disabled" />
</shape>
```

What I don't understand is why doing this is widening my button compare to when I don't change the background attribute. I tried to remove the radius or the ripple but it does nothing.
I don't set any padding either.